# C++ How can I build opencv for vs 2015 x86

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015, cmake, x86

I want to use opencv in my VS2015 C++ project and I need it exactly for x86 platform, not x64.
I used CMake as advised everywhere in the internet. What is more I tried to configure several versions of opencv - 2.4.9; 3.0.0; 3.1.0
And on each configuring and generating through CMake I get a lot of errors. 
Here's a log from CMake gui after configuring:

```
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:69 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0022 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:74 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0026 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.23506.0
The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.23506.0
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR - Failed
Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR
Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR - Failed
Check if the system is big endian
Searching 16 bit integer
Looking for sys/types.h
Looking for sys/types.h - found
Looking for stdint.h
Looking for stdint.h - found
Looking for stddef.h
Looking for stddef.h - found
Check size of unsigned short
Check size of unsigned short - done
Using unsigned short
Check if the system is big endian - little endian
Looking for fseeko
Looking for fseeko - not found
Looking for unistd.h
Looking for unistd.h - not found
Check size of off64_t
Check size of off64_t - failed
Looking for assert.h
Looking for assert.h - found
Looking for fcntl.h
Looking for fcntl.h - found
Looking for io.h
Looking for io.h - found
Looking for jbg_newlen
Looking for jbg_newlen - not found
Looking for mmap
Looking for mmap - not found
Looking for search.h
Looking for search.h - found
Looking for string.h
Looking for string.h - found
Looking for unistd.h
Looking for unistd.h - not found
CMake Warning at 3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:54 (message):
  ICV: Local copy of ICV package has invalid MD5 hash:
  d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e (expected:
  b59f865d1ba16e8c84124e19d78eec57)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:108 (_icv_downloader)
  cmake/OpenCVFindIPP.cmake:235 (include)
  cmake/OpenCVFindLibsPerf.cmake:12 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:526 (include)


ICV: Downloading ippicv_windows_20141027.zip...
CMake Error at 3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:71 (file):
  file DOWNLOAD HASH mismatch

    for file: [D:/opencv-3.0/opencv/sources/3rdparty/ippicv/downloads/windows-b59f865d1ba16e8c84124e19d78eec57/ippicv_windows_20141027.zip]
      expected hash: [b59f865d1ba16e8c84124e19d78eec57]
        actual hash: [d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e]
             status: [6;"Couldn't resolve host name"]

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:108 (_icv_downloader)
  cmake/OpenCVFindIPP.cmake:235 (include)
  cmake/OpenCVFindLibsPerf.cmake:12 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:526 (include)


CMake Error at 3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:75 (message):
  ICV: Failed to download ICV package: ippicv_windows_20141027.zip.
  Status=6;"Couldn't resolve host name"
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:108 (_icv_downloader)
  cmake/OpenCVFindIPP.cmake:235 (include)
  cmake/OpenCVFindLibsPerf.cmake:12 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:526 (include)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/opencv-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "D:/opencv-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

And this log is after generating:

```
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:69 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0022 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:74 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0026 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


CMake Warning at 3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:54 (message):
  ICV: Local copy of ICV package has invalid MD5 hash:
  d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e (expected:
  b59f865d1ba16e8c84124e19d78eec57)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:108 (_icv_downloader)
  cmake/OpenCVFindIPP.cmake:235 (include)
  cmake/OpenCVFindLibsPerf.cmake:12 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:526 (include)


ICV: Downloading ippicv_windows_20141027.zip...
CMake Error at 3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:71 (file):
  file DOWNLOAD HASH mismatch

    for file: [D:/opencv-3.0/opencv/sources/3rdparty/ippicv/downloads/windows-b59f865d1ba16e8c84124e19d78eec57/ippicv_windows_20141027.zip]
      expected hash: [b59f865d1ba16e8c84124e19d78eec57]
        actual hash: [d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e]
             status: [6;"Couldn't resolve host name"]

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:108 (_icv_downloader)
  cmake/OpenCVFindIPP.cmake:235 (include)
  cmake/OpenCVFindLibsPerf.cmake:12 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:526 (include)


CMake Error at 3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:75 (message):
  ICV: Failed to download ICV package: ippicv_windows_20141027.zip.
  Status=6;"Couldn't resolve host name"
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:108 (_icv_downloader)
  cmake/OpenCVFindIPP.cmake:235 (include)
  cmake/OpenCVFindLibsPerf.cmake:12 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:526 (include)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/opencv-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "D:/opencv-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Both CMakeOutput.log and CMakeError.log are not readable. They are full of unreadable characters.

How can I get this vc14 x86 version of opencv!?
I'm stuck.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to download ippicv_windows_20141027.zip from a bad url. Either that, or the download is corrupt. There isn't a way to tell since you left out the CMakeLists.txt

Comment: what i can see in your logs is the "Couldn't resolve host name"... do you have internet while doing cmake? the cmake from opencv is trying to download some missing modules, to use them.

Comment: khm.. I'm at work and we use proxy here.. maybe that is the problem.. well, I'll try to build opencv at home. Thank for the idea.

Comment: you can try downloading manually? this is the link from [github of the file](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_3rdparty/raw/ippicv/master_20141027/ippicv/ippicv_windows_20141027.zip) just put  it where it says it should be, maybe it works... however, you are also using quite an old version.... 2014!! You should try to get newer sources :)

Answer (score 0):

In OpenCVConfig.cmake,

```
if(MSVC)
  message("CMAKE_CL_64 is ${CMAKE_CL_64}")
  if(CMAKE_CL_64)
    set(OpenCV_ARCH x64)
  elseif((CMAKE_GENERATOR MATCHES "ARM") OR ("${arch_hint}" STREQUAL "ARM") OR (CMAKE_VS_EFFECTIVE_PLATFORMS MATCHES "ARM|arm"))
    # see Modules/CmakeGenericSystem.cmake
    set(OpenCV_ARCH ARM)
  else()
    set(OpenCV_ARCH x86)
  endif()
```