# How to build and install OpenCV 4.2.0 for x86?

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, cmake, x86

Im trying to build the newest OpenCV version ([4.2.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/4.2.0/)) for x86/32bit on Windows for Visual Studio. However there is only 1 `OpenCVConfig.cmake` in the finished build (`opencv/build/win-install/x86/vc16/lib/OpenCVConfig.cmake` - there is no bin folder).

**What i've tried:**

1. I've downloaded and executed the latest version (opencv-4.2.0-vc14_vc15.exe)
2. I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790736/c-how-can-i-build-opencv-for-vs-2015-x86) SO thread and added the short snippet in my `opencv/build/OpenCVConfig.cmake`
3. Downloaded Cmake [3.17](https://cmake.org/download/) and installed via the installer
4. Started the Cmake GUI - set source code to `opencv/sources` and binaries to `opencv/build`
5. Choose `Visual Studio 16-2019` as generator and options to `win32`
6. Configured Proxy for the downloads and clicked on Generate.

I got no noticeable Errors in the build process. The last lines of the console are:

```
Install to:                    C:/Users/user/opencv/build/install

Configuring done
Generating done
```

There is also no `install` folder inside `opencv/install`. I think it installs to `opencv/build/win-install`.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't actually build OpenCV. All you've done so far is used CMake to generate a solution for Visual Studio.

Comment: For Visual Studio I recommend [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) for package management.

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks, just realized this too! However when i now try to build and install in VS i still get the error: No configuration for debug/release/win32.